# Github Actions Error: No such file or directory

Tags: github-actions

Trying to troubleshoot my terraform init step, but I'm getting `Error: No such file or directory`

Even if I add the `pwd` as step 2 shown below, still getting `Error: No such file or directory`.  This is working in other pipelines, but none of the new pipelines are working with the same commands.

Was there an update to GHA?  I know they updated Helm, but did something else change that would adjust the behavior?

```
update-terraform-env:
    name: "Create or Update Terraform Environment"
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR }}
      
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Source
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get directory
        run: pwd

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1.2.1
        with:
          terraform_version: 0.13.0

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: tf-init
        run: terraform init
```

Answer (score 0):

The `env.TERRAFORM_WORKING_DIR` was initialized to a path that didn't exist.  (`development` which didn't exist, instead of `develop` which did).

The error of `Error: No such file or directory` was misleading as it seemed that the step command is failing, when it's actually the working directory for the entire job.